# How do I fix my Bluetooth device in Xubuntu 20.04?

Tags: bluetooth

After recent package upgrades on Friday, July 16th, the Bluetooth device on my motherboard quit working. (Apt's history log here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zKFyYkNBXn/plain/) I've attempted to downgrade and adjust the packages since the install, but none of those attempts have restored the device to functioning (though I did not exactly exactly reverse Friday's upgrade either).

The Bluetooth device is an Intel Wireless-AC 3168NGW device that handles both WiFi and Bluetooth with a shared antenna installed on a Gigabyte X570 AORUS ELITE WIFI motherboard. Here's the output of `lspci`, `lsusb`, and `dmesg` commands: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2Sy9FnvkGk/plain/. Also, some `dmesg` output captured more recently after bootup (before most of the relevant data is consumed by the ever-cycling Bluetooth crashout): http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pC3ttfsRfJ/plain/.

I tried booting to a 20.04 install USB. The "try Xubuntu" option was also not able to use the Bluetooth. Would new firmware have overwritten working firmware or something?

I'm pretty stumped about how to actually fix this and being unable to use the Bluetooth keyboard and mouse are major pains right now. Also, blueman-tray keeps popping up, crashing out, restarting again... up down, up down, up down... Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: After reading the self-answer I chose to close-vote as non-reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I have forgotten some basic troubleshooting, obviously!

So, the fix turned out to be really easy. After shutting down the computer, I actually unplugged it from the wall for a while... and 60 seconds later, I plugged it back in. Apparently, the motherboard just wasn't really powering down with the computer plugged in, so the Intel Wireless-AC 3168NGW wasn't really powering off and resetting itself.

At least it's a super-easy fix! Hope it helps one of you... though I'll feel kinda stupid for a while...